# Change Xcode parameter in order to get more space

Tags: xcode

I am an owner of macbook pro 2011 model non retina. It's 13 inches and it's kinda hard to actually code in it efficient. Is there a way to downscale the UI of xcode in order to get a bit more space for my development user interface? If yes how is that possible? I have searched the net for ages and couldnt find something.. I would appreciate if i could have some assistance. Thanks

Comment: @trojanfoe there is a way of increasing in software the resolution of your screen. That did increase the UI scale of xcode but made the letters really small..

Comment: Why not use some other editor?

Comment: @TamásZahola would you suggest any good editor for ios development that includes the ability of adding al the connections between storyboard  and the class without programming?if yes which one? But i would prefer to use xcode and have a bit more space thanks

Comment: Yeah, for storyboards and interface builder there's no alternative...

Comment: @TamásZahola well i really appreciate your help. Tbh i am looking for a solution to get more space with xcode rather than change the editor i am using.. If you read some comments above i did find a solution a while ago and it worked but i was looking if there is a better one.

Comment: use extension monitor!!!

Comment: @Mr.T i know that! But i am looking a more portable solution